# Centering full page html content

Tags: html, css

After a number of hours of trying different styling I am unable to achieve the effect I want.

I have something similar to the following:

```
<section class="section-container>
<div>
full screen content which I want to centered (equal space above and below) 
and left aligned. 
</div>
</section>
<section class="section-container>
<div>
full screen content which I want to centered (equal space above and below) 
and left aligned. 
</div>
</section>
```

I have each section taking up 100vh which achieves the full screen effect I want. However, I now want equal spacing above and below which I have been unable to get (it often seems I'm trying to trick css into doing what I want). A couple of things I have tried

```
.section-container{
height:100vh;
margin-top:50%;
}

.section-container{
height:100vh;
margin: 50% 0;
}
.section-container{
height:100vh;
vertical-align: center;
}
```

What is it I'm doing wrong/misunderstadning? And is there a general techinque for achieving vertically centered content like this.

Answer (score 3):

[There are a lot of ways to do what you want](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/). However, the easiest way to get centered content in modern CSS is probably with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). To center all of that content, try the following code:

```css
.section-container{
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-container">
  <div>
    full screen content which I want to centered (equal space above     and below) and left aligned. 
  </div>
</section>
```

`align-items` will center the children of the flexed element vertically, assuming no other flex properties. If you also want to center the content horizontally, add the property `justify-content: center`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont clearly understand your question, do you want to vertically center the text content inside the wrapper, i have made a snippet for what i got from you

```css
.section-container{
height:100vh;
margin-bottom:50%;
background: red;
display: flex;
align-items:center;
color: #fff;
}
.section-container:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="section-container">
<div>
full screen content which I want to centered (equal space above and below) 
and left aligned. 
</div>
</section>
<section class="section-container">
<div>
full screen content which I want to centered (equal space above and below) 
and left aligned. 
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your notice, iwas about editing my answer to add the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.tipue.com/blog/center-a-div/) is a good resource on understanding centering of elements. Most likely the issue comes from using `vh` or `vw`. Below is an example that should work with your own work. See that I used px or % instead of `vh` or `vw`.

```
.section-container{
  width: 500px;
}

div {
   margin: 0 auto; 
}

OR

.section-container{
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  margin-right: 10%; 
  margin-left: 10%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `flexbox`.

1. First, you'll make the `.section-container` elements as `flex`
   containers by adding the `display: flex` rule.
2. Then, you'll use `justify-content: center` to distribute same
   spacing in both right and left.
3. Lastly, apply `align-items: center` to distribute same spacing in
   both top and bottom.

Here's a revised version of your attempt :

```css
.section-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex; /** the element becomes a flex container that'll make the life much more easier **/
  justify-content: center; /** center horizontally (same spacing left and right) **/
  align-items: center; /** center vertically (same spacing top and bottom) **/
  border: 1px solid red; /** just for the example so the result can be seen **/
}
```

```html
<section class="section-container">
  <div>
    full screen content which I want to centered (equal space above and below) and left aligned.
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section-container">
  <div>
    full screen content which I want to centered (equal space above and below) and left aligned.
  </div>
</section>
```

> Learn more about [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Hope I pushed you further.